# How solved "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'"?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, scikit-learn, transform

I have a tow-dimensional array with strings in each of the elements. I am trying to use a `transform()` using `sklearn.feature_extraction.text` to convert text data into numerical . However, I am getting an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "/Users/asma/Desktop/q.py", line 13, in <module>
        Fit = stand.fit(Lower)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 2053, in fit
        X = super().fit_transform(raw_documents)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1330, in fit_transform
        vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, self.fixed_vocabulary_)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1201, in _count_vocab
        for feature in analyze(doc):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 113, in _analyze
        doc = preprocessor(doc)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 71, in _preprocess
        doc = doc.lower()
    AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

this is the coding

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

sting_array = ["hEllO","iNteRneT","pEopLe","sKay","sds","gbrhn","rHy"]
Array2D = np.reshape(sting_array, [-1, 1])
Lower = np.char.lower(Array2D)

stand = TfidfVectorizer()
 #fit data
Fit = stand.fit(Lower)
 #transform data
x_scaled =stand.transform(Lower)

print(x_scaled)
```

Although I am using `Lower = np.char.lower (Array2D)`, but I got the same error!!
Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: you should consider reimporting numpy or rather reinstalling numpy

Comment: What's the purpose of `Array2D = np.reshape(sting_array, [-1, 1])`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the code for the lowercase. Because the `stand.fit` will do that automatically.

```
...
sting_array = ["hEllO","iNteRneT","pEopLe","sKay","sds","gbrhn","rHy"]

stand = TfidfVectorizer()
 #fit data
Fit = stand.fit(sting_array)
 #transform data
x_scaled =stand.transform(sting_array)

print(x_scaled)
```